# Binding Devexpress combobox edit with different displayed text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

I have a winforms application , In which I'd like to **bind** these values

> Disponible (D) : D
>
> NSFP (S) : S
>
> Archivé (A) : A
>
> NC (N) :N

to a `DevExpressComboBoxEdit` control, ie items text  will be `Disponible (D), NSFP (S), Archivé (A), NC (N)` and values `D,S,A,N` because the items source type is `varchar(1)`.

So How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: add more code, where you get items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task I suggest you use the [LookUpEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) editor:

```
LookUpEdit lookUpEdit = new LookUpEdit();
var dataSource = new List<Data> { 
    new Data(){ Value = 'D', Display ="Disponible (D)"},
    new Data(){ Value = 'S', Display ="NSFP (S)"},
    new Data(){ Value = 'A', Display ="Archivé (A)"},
    new Data(){ Value = 'N', Display ="NC (N)"},
};
lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = dataSource;
lookUpEdit.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("Value") { Visible = false });
lookUpEdit.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("Display"));
lookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = "Display";
lookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember = "Value";
lookUpEdit.Properties.ShowHeader = false;
lookUpEdit.EditValue = 'A';
```

Here the `Data` class looks like this:

```
public class Data {
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public char Value { get; set; }
}
```